# Can you break somebody else's attunement on a magic item?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, attunement

My players stole a magic item from a Dragon's Hoard but the dragon is still alive and attuned to it. Is there any way for the players to break the dragon's attunement?

Answer (score 39):

#### Just attune to the item or stay away from the dragon for 24 hours.

The [rules for attunement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#Attunement) state:

> **A creature’s attunement to an item ends** if the creature no longer satisfies the prerequisites for attunement, **if the item has been more than 100 feet away for at least 24 hours**, if the creature dies, or **if another creature attunes to the item.**

So if you are away from the dragon, its attunement will end within a day, or alternatively, just attune to the item yourself:

> Attuning to an item requires a creature to spend a short rest focused on only that item while being in physical contact with it (this can't be the same short rest used to learn the item's properties).

You could also just kill the dragon, but that is obviously the most difficult of your available options. Other methods include diplomacy and mind control, which again, are far more difficult given that you already have the item.

Comment: Wait, so attunement is basically like Bluetooth pairing?  :-)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Nah, cause the old partner is completely forgotten for attunement.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson - the item forgets the owner ... but my guess is, the dragon won't forget the adventurers not the item they stole from him :D