# Can you force a target to lose attunement to magic items?

Tags: dnd-5e, attunement

This is a theory crafting exercise, answerable from a PC's or DM's perspective:

Is there a strategic or tactical way to force a player or other NPC to lose their attunement to a magical item using game mechanics, class abilities, or spells?

The ability to turn off a BBEG's acess to their artifacts or a clever DM using it to disrupt a player's favorite setup could add interesting or novel tactical play to a sesson.  Are there any options using RAW to disrupt, dispell, or break a characters attunment to a (or all) of their magic items?

Similar Questions:

[Can you break somebody else's attunement on a magic item?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/195486/can-you-break-somebody-elses-attunement-on-a-magic-item)

Comment: This is the same question as one of the similar questions you linked so I have closed this as a duplicate. If you think the answer to the linked question is incomplete, you might consider posting a bounty explaining such.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov - Noted.  An argument could be made for specific VS general.  They were asking for a specific use case scenario - and given only a single point awnser.  I am asking for a known summary of stategic game mechancis (If they exist).  =)

Comment: I can see the point in asking a separate question, since the dupe target asks specifically for ways to break attunement of an item which you already have, and not attunement on a creature currently using an item in their possession. Which are very different situations. I believe the issue here is that the linked question is much more specific than what its title implies.